# How do I display response body using node.js and postman collection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postman-newman

I can't seem to frame my question correctly to get a useful answer.

I have a Postman collection. I have exported it as a JSON and I want to use node.js/newman to run it in several parallel instances to validate a fix for some code that wasn't thread safe.

I got a sample script (shown below) and made some small mods for my needs.
I installed node.js and populated the registry with common libraries. (package.json shown below)

I type node loadTest.js and the script runs and executes all my calls.

I want to display and/or save the response body so I can go over the data in the response and I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out how to do that. I have very little familiarity with this environment (node.js) so I'm finding no useful answers.

**Sample script with mods.**

```
    async = require('async'),
    newman = require('newman'),
    json = require('json'),

    /**
     * Collection run options.
     *
     * @type {Object}
     */
    development = {
        collection: path.join(__dirname, 'developmentserver.json'),
        reporters: 'cli'
    },

    test = {
        collection: path.join(__dirname, 'testserver.json'),
        reporters: 'cli'
    },

    /**
     * Collection runners.
     *
     * @param {Function} done - A callback function that marks the end of the current collection run, when called.
     */
    devCollectionRun = function (done) {
        newman.run(development, done);
    };

    testCollectionRun = function (done) {
        newman.run(test, done);
    };


/**
* Execute collection runs.
*/
async.parallel([
    devCollectionRun,
    devCollectionRun,
    devCollectionRun
],

function (err, results) {
    err && console.error(err);

    results.forEach(function (result) {
        var failures = result.run.failures;
        var outp = result.collection.name + ' ran successfully.';
        console.info(failures.length ? JSON.stringify(failures.failures, null, 2) : outp);
    });
});
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "loadtest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "loadTest.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "loadTest"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "keywords": [],
  "description": "runs load test package",
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^3.2.4",
    "cli": "^1.0.1",
    "console": "^0.7.2",
    "json": "^11.0.0",
    "newman": "^5.3.2",
    "newman-reporter-json-summary": "^1.0.14"
  }
}
```

**Edit: (Added here because it's just a wall of text in a comment)**

I ended up adding the log statements in the collection json in the "exec" section like:

```
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "pm.test(\"Status must not equal E\", function () {\r",
                            "    var jsonData = pm.response.json();\r",
                            "    pm.expect(jsonData[0].STATUS_FLAG).not.to.eql(\"E\");\r",
                            "    console.log(\"Case Number: \" + jsonData[0].CASE_NO);\r",
                            "    console.log(\"Address: \" + jsonData[0].EAP_ADDRS);\r",
                            "    console.log(\"Value: \" + jsonData[0].AVM_VALUE);\r",
                            "});"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript"
                    }
```

If there is a better way to do this I would love to hear it, but this works well enough for my purpose.